# rake db:migrate error for generating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

after using rails generate model email:string name:string i got this error for rake db:migrate

```
rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.
/home/abhishek/RubymineProjects/untitled/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/abhishek/RubymineProjects/untitled/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/abhishek/RubymineProjects/untitled/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Why you ignore the error message? _Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes._

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper command syntax  to create a model

`rails generate model email:string name:string`

Use this instead:

`rails generate model ModelName email:string name:string`

and then use

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in migration. Problem is in your `routes.rb` file. Could you provide your `routes.rb` file here.

Comment: i did not touch routes.rb trust me it's fine when i created a new app and did the same it worked i dont know what happened , anyways thank you for your time